# Selecting randint from range

Tags: python

```
from random import randint
number_of_trials = 100
range_of_random_numbers = 1000
for each in number_of_trials:
    print randint(range(range_of_random_numbers))
```

I am a beginner to python. When I try running the above code I get the error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I'm trying to get a random number from a range (defined in range_of_numbers) to print a certain amount of times (defined in number_of_trials). Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to make an iterable (list if you're using Python 2.x) which will be used for iteration.

and you need to pass two integer to [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint), not an interable (or list):

```
from random import randint

number_of_trials = 100
range_of_random_numbers = 1000
for each in range(number_of_trials):
    print randint(0, range_of_random_numbers)
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks. I knew I was missing something but I was looking more towards what was inside the for loop rather than what defined it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to use is choice.

```
from random import choice
```

Then change

```
print randint(range(range_of_random_numbers))
```

to

```
print choice(range(range_of_random_numbers))
```

The choice function will randomly pick an element from a non-empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

One issue and one suggestion in your code -

1. You are doing - `for each in number_of_trails:` - this is wrong, you are trying to iterate over an integer, you should do - `for each in range(number_of_trails):` .
2. The best to use here is [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) (Instead of `randint()`). Especially if the `range_of_random_numbers` is not continuous.

Example -

```
from random import choice
number_of_trials = 100
range_of_random_numbers = 1000
for each in range(number_of_trials):
    print choice(range(range_of_random_numbers))
```

---

From [documentation of `random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) -

> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
from random import randint
number_of_trials = 100
range_of_random_numbers = 1000
for each in range(number_of_trials):
    print randint(range(range_of_random_numbers))
```

You got the error due to the fact int object are not iterable that is :

i.e)

```
for a in 1:
    print a

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```